# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in JavaScript fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am getting a TypeError in JavaScript when trying to make a fetch request to "/users/add". The error message says "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined (reading 'data') at register:38:66".

I am making two fetch requests, the first one to get the API key works fine, but the second one to "/users/add" using the API key is causing the error. The response from the second request doesn't seem to have the "data" property.

I have tried logging the response to the console, but I am still not sure what is causing the error.

Here is the relevant code:

```
let apiKey = null;

fetch("/api-key", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => apiKey = data)
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

function register() {
  let user = document.getElementById("user").value;
  let pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

  // Post request to /users/add using the API key
  fetch("/users/add", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": apiKey
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: user,
      password: pass,
      api_key: apiKey
    })
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Request JSON data:", JSON.parse(response.config.data));
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to add user. Response status: " + response.status);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log("User added successfully:", data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error adding user:", error);
    });
}
```

Node.js:

```
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const api_key = req.body.api_key;

    bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => {
        if (api_key != real_api_key) {
            return res.status(400).json('Error: Incorrect API key');
        }

        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err);
        }

        const newUser = new User({username, password: hashedPassword, api_key});

        newUser.save()
            .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    });
});
```

Comment: a `fetch` response object doesn't have a `.config` property

Comment: .then(response => {  console.log(JSON.stringify(response)) .... })   to see what is the structure of the response object.   At fetch("/api-key", { ....  .then(data => apiKey = data) ... the data is an incomming parameter, you can set any name e.g. .then(Mydata => apiKey = Mydata)